# comparative phrase 'more than'

Tags: phrase-usage, comparatives

I don't know the meaning of **the phrase** in this sentence

> We are seldom exposed only to a single contaminant in the
>   environment-but **more often than not** to a cocktail of chemical
>   mixture.

How to understand 'more often than not'?

Comment: Multiple chemical exposure happens more times than single chemical exposure.

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/more+often+than+not

Comment: The sentence is asserting that exposures to multiple chemicals at a time occur more frequently than exposures to single chemicals.

Comment: _**More often than not**_ is a fixed phrase, an idiom. It just means 'often'. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

"More often than not" describes a degree of probability which is greater than 50%.

Comment: As Richard Kayser has already said. // It probably _does_ describe an observed relative frequency, which would be used to work out the empirical probability.  Or it may even be a loose expression not meaning anything more specific than 'often'. All this has already been said.

Answer (score 0):

I would think of this phrase by rephrasing and making it a sentence like, "There are **more often** times when we are exposed to a cocktail of chemical mixture **than** the times when we are **not** exposed to one.      More often than not=as often as not=usually. Hope this helps...

Comment: It is unclear whether the intent is to imply that during more than 50% of your existence you are exposed to a "cocktail", or that more than 50% of the time  that you're exposed to contaminants it's a "cocktail" rather than a single chemical.